# Read Outlook Items from self-written ribbon in Visual Studio 2015 in C#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, add-in, ribbon

I am writing my first ribbon-add-in for outlook 2016 using Visual Studio 2015 and C#.
After some difficulties finally I got my "hello world" working. 
But what I would like to do now is access the currently displayed outlook item in my C# code which can either be a mailitem or an appointment request or a meeting. 
Unfortunately it is hard to find as I am not quite sure, what to look for. 
Maybe someone has some hints or maybe an coding example how to start. 
My ribbon is placed in Microsoft.Outlook.Explorer, Microsoft.Outlook.Appointment, Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Read, Microsoft.Outlook.Mail.Compose

Thanks for your help

here my example code

```
private void btnIssueFromMail_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    //Read Mail item
    string subject;
    string body;
}
```

Comment: If you need tutor for outlook addin development, let me know. I will give full course training .

Comment: @Shyamsundarshah - thanks for your offer. Maybe I will ask you later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RibbonControlEventArgs.Control.Context` and cast it to Inspector object. You can then use `Inspector.CurrentItem` to cast to the appropriate item type (e.g. `MailItem` or `AppointmentItem`).